# Event Schedule 12 Teams / 4 Activities / Play Each Activity 3X / Play Each Team Once

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, permutations, combinations

Anyone know how to schedule an event where you have 12 teams and 4 different activities. The different activities all have the ability to host two of the same activities simultaneous. The different activities will have each team plays each event 3 times and plays each team once. I added a picture of what I am working with but as you get towards the end I can't solve it. Thanks
[image]